# Does the circuit need a wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electrical-resistance, batteries

I watched a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/oI_X2cMHNe0?feature=shared) of Derek from Veritasium in which at 13:20, he claims that the lightbulb will turn on even if the circuit is broken, which astonishes me.

How can it be possible while when I cut the wire from the source to my lightbulb in my house, the light goes away immediately? Is there any special condition so that the circuit is always complete even when the wire is broken?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Derek is talking about the absolute most extreme corner case possible.  It does not line up with your intuition.

Derek is right that electricity can flow without wires.  In his example, he creates what we usually call an antenna, and indeed some electricity does flow from one side to the other, despite there being no wires.

I fault his example a bit because he really isn't lighting a lightbulb with the power transmitted through the air by his antennas.  Lighting a lightbulb takes *way* more power than his setup would transmit.  But the tiniest fraction of power would indeed be transmitted this way.  You'd never see it, because it wouldn't produce enough photons for the human eye to see, but power would transmit.

A better demonstration of this effect would be the use of a Van de Graffe generator to [light a neon tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IQkUlT8oZc) at a distance.   This uses much higher voltages.

What Derek shows does indeed happen in your house, with AC voltages.  It happens on such a ludicrously small scale that we usually don't even think about it.

We *do* care about it on a nationwide scale.  You've probably seen the very high voltage lines which are way up on the tall power poles.  Not the little 13kV ones that you might see in your neighborhood.  The big ones where they put 400kV across the lines.  In those cases, there's a frustrating effect called parasitic capacitance.  Basically, the power lines form a structure like Derek's antenna.  Some small fraction of the power is indeed lost going straight from one wire to another.  It's small, and usually ignored.  But on very long lengths of wire with very high voltages, it becomes a non-trivial source of losses for the power company.  Thus for very long hauls, it is common to switch from AC to DC.  These effects get more pronounced at higher frequencies.  Going down to lower frequencies makes the effect smaller - and DC is basically 0 Hz.

The effect is important enough to warrant the extra effort it takes to go from AC to DC to AC.  They build huge thyristor [valve halls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valve_hall) like this one:

[image: Valve Hall]

All of that effort is because there is indeed power that transmits via the electric field through the air.  Its worth the cost of building these structures to avoid it. On human scales, it's a small effect, but it does add up on larger scales.

It also adds up on small scales too.  If the gap between the conductors is small, the effect is more pronounced.  In a controlled setting, we call these devices "capacitors," and they are a critical part of nearly every electric device out there.

Answer (score 1):

> at 13:20, he claims that the lightbulb will turn on even if the circuit is broken,

If the wire is broken, the lightbulb will "turn on" only until the signal travels down the wire to the point of the break and reflects back. Once the reflection reaches the bulb, the bulb will turn off again.

(As others have said, the bulb doesn't turn fully on, it only receives a relatively small current.)

> when I cut the wire from the source to my lightbulb in my house, the light goes away immediately ?

The lightbulb doesn't turn off immediately. It takes several nanoseconds for the wires disconnected by the switch to discharge, and it probably takes many milliseconds for the lightbulb filament to cool off enough to stop glowing.

However your eyes and brain are only able to distinguish the time of events that happen 10's of milliseconds apart, so these delays of nanoseconds or milliseconds are too short for us to detect, and we perceive them as being "instant".

> Does the circuit need a wire?

The light bulb "turning on" before the signal from the battery is able to traverse the whole wire structure is possible because of capacitance between the two parts of the wire in Derek's circuit.

This capacitance allows the electric field from the outgoing wire to excite a current in the returning wire, even though there hasn't been time for a current pulse to traverse the whole structure.

Remember that the rules (like KCL and KVL) that we use for most circuit analysis depend on the *lumped circuit approximation*, and Derek's circuit in this video violates the assumptions needed to make that approximation valid. We can mostly fix this by considering the parasitic capacitance between the wire components and the parasitic inductance of the wire, to form a finite-element model of the structure, which could give modeling results very close to what is shown in Derek's full EM simulations.

But if we ignore those effects and assume the wires in this distributed circuit behave like ideal wires in circuit theory, we won't model the circuit accurately.

Edit

In comments you asked,

> At precisely 11:30 in the video of Derek, it is showned that the electric field of the battery impacts directly the electrons in the lightbulb without passing through the chain of electrons of the wire from the battery to the lightbulb.

Here is the image from Derek's video at 11:28:

[image]

Notice that it shows electrons moving (blue dots) both in the bulb, **and** in the wires connected to the bulb.

Physically, the bulb filament is just another piece of wire. It just happens to be a high resistance wire so that when current flows through it, it will heat up and glow.

What happened here is that because of parasitic capacitance (the electric field between the outgoing wire and the returning wire), current starts to flow in the returning wire. When current flows in the funny part of the returning wire (the bulb filament) the bulb heats up and emits light.

> Therefore I have impression that the electric current has nothing to do with the movement of electrons in the wire (as it seems unnecessary),

This is simply not correct. The meaning of the word *current* is "movement of charge". It has everything to do with movement of electrons or other particles that carry charge.

We also have the term *displacement current*, which means a changing displacement field. In the case where the material where the field is found is vacuum or air, this is very close to the same thing as a changing electric field. We call this a "current" because it has the same effect (it produces a magnetic field) in Maxwell's equations as an ordinary moving-charge current.

In an electromagnetic wave the displacement current can exist without any moving charge to initiate it. But in a capacitor structure, the displacement charge is initiated by the moving charges on the capacitor plates. This is what is happening in Derek's experiment---the two wires are acting as two capacitor plates. In a lumped circuit analysis with capacitors, displacement current is what maintains the continuity of a current (allowing KVL to be satisfied) through capacitive devices with no path for charged particles to flow.

In Derek's experiment, we can say that the displacement current completes the loop from the outgoing wire (the one connected to the battery and switch) to the returning wire (the one connected to the bulb) during the period where the ordinary current (moving electrons) hasn't had time to propagate out to the end of the wire and back.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation (and the one in the other question). However I'm always confused. At precisely 11:30 in the video of Derek, it is showned that the electric field of the battery impacts directly the electrons in the lightbulb without passing through the chain of electrons of the wire from the battery to the lightbulb. Therefore I have impression that the electric current has nothing to do with the movement of electrons in the wire (as it seems unnecessary), which contrast my understanding that the current is the movement of charged particles. Can you please explain it to me ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your edit incorporating my question in the comment. Could you kindly elaborate more what do you mean by "reflect back" in the first paragraph of your answer ? What is the reflection you are talking about ? I mean it is the reflection of "what kind of signal", what causes this reflection, why this signal has to reflect back ? (i have seen it in the video but i don't get it). And why should the light turn off when the signal reflects back ? Many thanks!

Comment: It surprises me when you said the light will turn off after receiving the reflected signal. Because as I understand, the light turns of because it receives some kind of signal, not turn off because of the signal, right ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge, that was in the case where the wire is broken at some distant point. The break causes a negative reflection, so the reflection opposes the initial capacitively coupled signal that allows the light to turn partly on. In the case where the wire is not broken, the reflection is what turns the light fully on.

Comment: Hi, can I ask it is the reflection of "what" ? maybe you mean the reflection of the electric field...?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge the reflection of the signal sent down the wire (or the wavefront guided by the wire) when the switch was closed.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single wire that goes from your power company to your house. Instead there is a "transformer" in which the wire from the power company "induces" current in the wire to your house, without the two conductors actually touching each other. Instead the two conductors are wrapped around the same piece of magnetizable iron. The iron makes the power transfer more efficient (or "increases the mutual inductance"), but electrical induction is still a phenomenon if the shared volume is some non-magnetic material like plastic or air.

Inductance doesn't transmit a *constant* current across a gap. Instead, a *changing* current on one side of the transformer causes a *changing* current to appear on the other side. Inductance is a phenomenon best described using the magnetic field associated with the current. You can also transmit a changing current across an insulating gap via "capacitance," which is associated with the *electric* field.

Your power company sends electric current to your house across these insulating gaps by sending you a *constantly* changing current, or an "alternating current."

In the case of two very long wires (search term: "transmission line"), you might be tempted to think of the switch as sending current down one wire, where it will eventually reach the end and return down the other wire.  It's easier to see what happens if you imagine the two wires are near each other in a "cable," whether that's like the parallel-wire cables in your wall, or the twisted-pair cables that we use for short-distance computer networks, or the coaxial cables that are associated with television signals. (If your circuit is a light-minute long, as in your linked video, any reasonable distance between the wires will be "small.") The closer the two cables are, the larger their mutual inductance and mutual capacitance. As your current forces its way down the one wire in the cable, there are changing electric and magnetic fields associated with the leading edge of the current. These changing fields induce a return current in the other wire — regardless of what happens at the other end of the cable.